# Building an editable tree of connected nodes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

I am trying to build a tree in React wherein one can add nodes and connect them and move them around, like the included picture.

[image]

How does one go about doing this?

I am working with create-react-app

I have tried all sorts of things but I keep having trouble with event.clientX/event.pageX, it keeps giving me random values which results in the nodes flickering.

To me it makes most sense to have the node-moving functionality on the level of the tree but that approach gives this flickering problem.

**How to prevent event.clientX from giving me random values?**

The problem i normally have is the flickering of the sort in this codepen:
https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-http-nnzx4?file=/src/App.js
(click and drag)

I have tried a number of things and the only way it works (altough buggy) is the way below where the node-moving functionality is on the level of the node:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect,useRef, useCallback, createRef} from 'react';
import "./PrinciplesTree.css"

function Line(props){

    function clickhandler(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
        props.deletenodeconnection(props.firstpoint.node_number,props.secondpoint.node_number)
    }

        const firstpoint = props.firstpoint
        const secondpoint = props.secondpoint

        var x1 = firstpoint.anchor_pos.anchorposx
        var y1 = firstpoint.anchor_pos.anchorposy
        var x2 = secondpoint.anchor_pos.anchorposx
        var y2 = secondpoint.anchor_pos.anchorposy

        if (x2 < x1) {
            var tmp;
            tmp = x2 ; x2 = x1 ; x1 = tmp;
            tmp = y2 ; y2 = y1 ; y1 = tmp;
        }
    
        var lineLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
        var m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
    
        var degree = Math.atan(m) * 180 / Math.PI;

        const divstyle =  {transformOrigin: 'top left', transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)', width: lineLength + "px", height: 1 + 'px', background: 'black', 
                            position: 'absolute', top: y1 + "px", left: x1 + "px"}


    return <div className='line' style={divstyle} onClick={clickhandler}></div>
}

function Node(props) {

      const [val, setval] = useState("Enter Principle");
      const node_number = props.nodeN
      const node_width = '150px'
      const anchorel = useRef(null)

      var offsetx = 0
      var offsety = 0

      let parentleft = 0
      let parentright = 0
      let parenttop = 0
      let parentbottom = 0

      const onclick = e =>{
        e.stopPropagation();

        const anchorpositionX = anchorel.current.getBoundingClientRect().left
        const anchorpositionY = anchorel.current.getBoundingClientRect().top

        const parentleft = e.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left
        const parenttop = e.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top

        const anchorpos = {anchorposx: anchorpositionX - parentleft, anchorposy: anchorpositionY - parenttop}

        props.connectnode.current(node_number,anchorpos)
      }

      const movehandler = e => {

            var newvalx = e.clientX-parentleft-offsetx
            var newvaly = e.clientY-parenttop-offsety
    
            if(((parentleft + newvalx) < parentright + 5 && (parentleft + newvalx) > parentleft - 5) && 
            (parenttop + newvaly > parenttop - 5 && parenttop + newvaly < parentbottom + 5)){
                props.updatenode(node_number,newvalx,newvaly)
            }
    
        
      }

     const addmovehandler = e => {

        
        const parent = e.target.parentElement

         parentleft = parent.getBoundingClientRect().left
         parentright = parent.getBoundingClientRect().right
         parenttop = parent.getBoundingClientRect().top
         parentbottom = parent.getBoundingClientRect().bottom

        offsetx = e.clientX - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left
        offsety = e.clientY - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top

        document.addEventListener('mouseover',movehandler)

        
     } 

     const removenodehandler = e =>{
        const parent = e.target.parentElement
        
        document.removeEventListener('mouseover',movehandler)
     }


    function edit(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(e.key === 'Enter'){
            setval(e.target.value)
        }

    }

    return <div className='node' style = {{left: props.posX, top: props.posY, width: node_width}} onMouseDown={addmovehandler} onMouseUp = {removenodehandler} onClick = {onclick}>
        <div className='anchor' ref={anchorel}></div>
        <textarea className = 'principle' name = {val} onKeyDown={edit} placeholder = {val}></textarea>
        <img src="cross.png" className='Cross' onClick={(e) => props.deletenode(node_number)}></img>
        </div>

}

function PrinciplesTree() {

    const [nodes, setnodes] = useState([]);
    const [connectednodes, setconnectednodes] = useState([]);

    const nodetoconnect = useRef(null)
    const connectnoderef = useRef() 

    useEffect(() => {

        setnodes([{key: 1, nodeN: 1, posX: 0, posY: 0, deletenode: deletenode, connectnode: connectnoderef, updatenode: updatenode}])
      },[]);
    

    const connectnode =  (nodeN,anchorpos)  => {
        
        if(nodetoconnect.current == null){
           nodetoconnect.current = {node_number: nodeN, anchor_pos: anchorpos}
        }else if(nodetoconnect.current != null && nodeN != nodetoconnect.current.node_number )
        {
            const node_to_add = nodetoconnect.current

            const firstnodenumber = nodetoconnect.current.node_number
            const secondnodenumber = nodeN

            var foundpair = false

            connectednodes.forEach(connectednode => {
                const firstnode = connectednode.first.node_number
                const secondnode = connectednode.second.node_number
                
                if((firstnode == firstnodenumber && secondnode == secondnodenumber) || (firstnode == secondnodenumber && secondnode == firstnodenumber)){
                    foundpair = true
                }

            })

            const newnodetoconnect = {first: node_to_add, second: {node_number: nodeN, anchor_pos: anchorpos}}

            if(foundpair == false){
                setconnectednodes(connectednodes => [...connectednodes,newnodetoconnect])
            }

            nodetoconnect.current = null
        }

    }

    connectnoderef.current = connectnode
    
    function deletenodeconnection(node1,node2){
        setconnectednodes(prevconnectednodes => {
            return prevconnectednodes.filter(connectednodes => !(connectednodes.first.node_number == node1 && connectednodes.second.node_number == node2))
        })       
    }

    const deletenode = (NodeN) =>{
        setnodes(prevnodes => {
            return prevnodes.filter(node => node.nodeN !== NodeN)})
    }

    const updatenode = (NodeN,newposx,newposy)=> {

        const updnode = {key: NodeN, nodeN: NodeN,  posX: newposx, posY: newposy, deletenode: deletenode, connectnode: connectnoderef, updatenode: updatenode}

        setnodes(nodes => (
            nodes.map(node => {
            if(node.nodeN == NodeN){
                return updnode
            }
            else return node }
            )))

    }

    function createnode(e){
        
        var el = e.target
        var posX=e.clientX-el.getBoundingClientRect().left
        var posY=e.clientY-el.getBoundingClientRect().top

        var newkey = 0;

       nodes.forEach(node => {
        if(node.key >= newkey){
            newkey = parseInt(node.key) + 1
        }
       });

        var newnode = {key: newkey, nodeN: nodes.length + 1, posX: posX, posY: posY, deletenode: deletenode, connectnode: connectnoderef, updatenode: updatenode}
        setnodes(nodes => [...nodes, newnode]);

    }
    
    return <div onClick={createnode} className='TreeCanvas'>
        {connectednodes.map(connectednode=> <Line firstpoint = {connectednode.first} secondpoint = {connectednode.second} deletenodeconnection={deletenodeconnection}/>)}
        {nodes.map(node => <Node key = {node.key} nodeN = {node.nodeN} posX = {node.posX} posY = {node.posY} deletenode = {node.deletenode} 
                                                                                                            connectnode = {node.connectnode} updatenode = {node.updatenode}/>)}
        </div>
}

export default PrinciplesTree;
```

Comment: You can use cytoscape package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Someone with the handle @wordswithjosh helped me a great deal on Reddit so I want to post his answer here for any people who might have the same question in the future.**

Gotcha - I've had some difficulty in the past getting draggable components to update smoothly. Where I've found the most success is usually resisting the urge to use the onDrag or onMouseMove event in the component, instead just using the mouse movement event to remember the position of the cursor, and instead using requestAnimationFrame to actually visually move the component.

This seems like overkill at first, but when you want multiple components to visually update simultaneously, I've found that the most reliable pattern is something like this:

```html
const TreeNode = () => {
  const [originalLeft, setOriginalLeft] = useState(0); // very rarely is an initial value of 'undefined' desirable; this is one of those times
  const [originalTop, setOriginalTop] = useState(0);
  const [left, setLeft] = useState();
  const [top, setTop] = useState();
  const [originalMouseX, setOriginalMouseX] = useState(0);
  const [originalMouseY, setOriginalMouseY] = useState(0);
  const [newMouseX, setNewMouseX] = useState(0);
  const [newMouseY, setNewMouseY] = useState(0);

  const mutableFrameRef = useRef({ paused: true, lastFrame: null });
  const selfRef = useRef(null);

  const loop = () => {
    // this shouldn't be necessary, but it's a failsafe to prevent
    // runaway recursive function behavior I've experienced in the
    // past when working with rAF
    if (mutableFrameRef.current.paused) return;

    // on every frame, set the new position of the div to its
    // previous position plus the current offset of the mouse
    setLeft(originalLeft + (newMouseX - originalMouseX));
    setTop(originalY + (newMouseY - originalMouseY));

    // this IS necessary, and is the default way of keeping a reference
    // to the handle used to cancel the last requested frame
    mutableFrameRef.current.lastFrame = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  };

  // not destructuring these params for performance
  const handleMouseMove = e => {
    setNewMouseX(e.clientX);
    setNewMouseY(e.clientY);
  };

  const handleMouseDown = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    setOriginalMouseX(clientX);
    setOriginalMouseY(clientY);
    setNewMouseX(clientX);
    setNewMouseY(clientY);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    mutableFrameRef.paused = true;
    cancelAnimationFrame(mutableFrameRef.current.lastFrame);
    // one more time just to be sure
    setLeft(originalLeft + (newMouseX - originalMouseX));
    setTop(originalY + (newMouseY - originalMouseY));

    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // default both our original and "live" top left corner coordinates to what they are on first paint
    const { x, y } = selfRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    setOriginalLeft(x);
    setOriginalTop(y);
    setLeft(x);
    setTop(y);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={selfRef}
      className='tree-node'
      style={{
        top,
        left
      }}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      draggable
    >
      // text stuff, tree node contents, etc - not relevant    
    </div>
  );
};
```

Full disclosure, I haven't tested this exact config, I kinda wrote it live  but I've used almost this exact pattern in the past, and I think you can get the idea - the main thing is that we only ask the browser to re-draw the div on every monitor refresh, which can drastically improve performance and help eliminate odd flickering.

You could, of course, avoid redrawing the div altogether by simply using the onDrag event to update the saved cursor position, and then update the actual drawn div location with onDragEnd, but I imagine the sort of "ghosting" behavior exhibited during the builtin HTML drag is not what you're looking for, and would not provide nearly as pretty of a user experience.